# Fetch sub-string from a column containing XML formatted String in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

As part of my query I am having one column which is having field value in two patterns as below

> First Pattern:-

```
"First Name:<a class='text-lg text-info'> David Peter </a><br>
Deadline:<a class='text-lg text-info'>2019-12-07 20:05:01</a><br>
Remarks:<a class='text-lg text-info'>Some remarks with multiple spaces</a><br>"
```

> Second Pattern:-

```
FirstName: <a class='text-lg text-info'>Alex Vander Veen</a><br>DeadLine: <a class='text-lg text-info'>2019-11-16 16:30:35</a>
```

I am trying to fetch out `First Name`/`FirstName` and `Deadline` value from these two fields.

Output needs to be as below :-

[image]

For getting this details `case statement` needs to be used on two patterns mentioned but I am really clueless on how to fetch only `First Name`/`FirstName` and `Deadline` from XML formatted string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to find solution to my above problem.

```
SELECT SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(A.FIELD_CONTENT,'>[^>]+<'),2,LENGTH(REGEXP_SUBSTR(A.FIELD_CONTENT,'>[^>]+<')) - 2 )  AS First_Name,
SUBSTR(SUBSTR(A.FIELD_CONTENT, REGEXP_INSTR(a.FIELD_CONTENT, '>', 1,4)+1),1, (REGEXP_INSTR(SUBSTR(A.FIELD_CONTENT, REGEXP_INSTR(a.FIELD_CONTENT, '>', 1,4)+1),'<',1,1) -1)) AS DEADLINE
FROM table_name1  a 
WHERE a.FIELD_CONTENT like '%First%'
```

I came up with this. If anyone has any suggestion to make this less expensive. Suggestions are welcomed.. :-)